# sql view getdate()

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, view

In my view I'm using:

```
GETDATE() as [Date of Issue]
```

However when checking the view, the Date of Issue column will always have the system date, instead I would like to have the actual date when the record was created i.e. DATETIME. Would that be possible?

Comment: Do you store that creation date anywhere?

Comment: Add tag for the DB engine.

Comment: no, the creation date should be the current timestamp

Comment: Then what's the issue with using `GETDATE()`? Either you store the date of creation and always return that, or you use `GETDATE()` and get the current datetime which is different at different times (!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the view to return the creation date of the record,
You need to have this value stored in the corresponding table.

Assuming you have such column, 
Define it in your view statement as shown below.

Otherwise, GetDate() function will always return the current date.

Modify:

```
select ColumnA,ColumnB, ... , GetDate() from [SomeTable]
```

To:

```
select ColumnA,ColumnB, ... , CreationDateColumn from [SomeTable]
```

Comment: OP does not have a `CreationDateColumn`